# How to give axes label to a histogram

Tags: plotting

I plotted a histogram and I used AxesLabel for labeling X axis and Y axis But it went wrong.
How to do it?.

```
Xarray = A @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 9], 3];

M = RandomSample[Xarray, 7]

Table[energies =  RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1.5], {Length@M}];

Total[energies/7], {i, 1000}];

Histogram[%, AxesLabel \[RightArrow] {"Average energy", "Number of times"}]
```

Comment: "But it went wrong" - how? Could you show a picture of what you've tried, and why you're dissatisfied with *Mathematica*'s output? (`AxesLabel` works fine, BTW.)

Comment: Try `Histogram[%, AxesLabel -> {"Average energy", "Number of times"}]`.

Comment: ... that is, replace `\[RightArrow]` with `->` or `\[Rule]`.

Answer (score 6):

`\[Rule]` is not the same as `\[RightArrow]`

Compare  this (it works):

```
 r = Table[Total[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1.5], {7}]/7], {i, 1000}];

 Histogram[r, AxesLabel \[Rule] {"Average energy", "Number of times"}]
```

With this (does not work)

```
 Histogram[r, AxesLabel \[RightArrow] {"Average energy", "Number of times"}]
```

`\[Rule]` is usually entered as two chars "->"